# Old hyperlinks are not accessible after migrating drupal 7

Tags: 7, migrations

My old website was located at 127.0.0.1/drupal address. Now I have hosted in live server. The website have content with hyperlinks. See the below screenshot-

[image]

All of the content is designed using CKEditor. I noticed that the hyperlinks are not accessible and returns 404 error. As an example; in the above screenshot, whenever I click on hyperlink for eula.pdf, it says file not found (404) error.

Old hyperlink-

```
http://127.0.0.1/drupal/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/eula.pdf
```

Hyperlink after migration-

```
http://www.example.com/drupal/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/eula.pdf
```

If I manually remove `/drupal` from the above URL and type `http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/eula.pdf`, the file opens successfully.

I have copied all the files from my computer to server. I have also imported the complete database to my new website.

Everything works fine except the hyperlinks, which I have inserted using CKEditor.

Comment: "not working" is the least descriptive explanation of what goes wrong there can be. To the best of my knowledge, there is no "ICMP" module. (Have you confused this with the [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) perhaps? Did you mean to include a link where you wrote "see here"?

Comment: @Letharion: Please see the updated question. I simply mean that hyperlinks are not accessible after migration. Notice the change in Hyperlink also.

Comment: @Ravi Joshi Have you tried the hyperlink url without "http://www.example.com"? Try to use "/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/eula.pdf" instead.

Comment: you say you copied all the files... did you also copy the database?

Comment: What do you mean by "not accessible"? Are they returning a "file not found (404)"? Is it because they are pointing to 127.0.0.1 instead of example.org? If yes, the question is how to rename URLs in the body of existing nodes because ckeditor used absolute links instead of relative.

Comment: The [Pathalogic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) module is an input filter which can correct paths in links and images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or the content was moved to a different server.

Comment: Another option is to use the [Search and Replace Scanner](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) module. You can search against the title, body and text content fields on all nodes in your system, and do a find and replace on your old links' protocols.

Comment: @J.Reynolds: Please have a look in my updated question. Earlier website was kept in `localhost` at `/drupal` directory, so the url was `http://127.0.0.1/drupal`. Now site is kept in live server with URL `http://www.example.com`. After migration, everything works fine except the hyperlinks created using CKEditor. These hyperklinks are returning 404 error. Sine there is an unnecessary `/drupal` coming in new URL.

Comment: @bgm: Please have a look in my updated question. Earlier website was kept in `localhost` at `/drupal` directory, so the url was `http://127.0.0.1/drupal`. Now site is kept in live server with URL `http://www.example.com`. After migration, everything works fine except the hyperlinks created using CKEditor. These hyperklinks are returning 404 error. Sine there is an unnecessary `/drupal` coming in new URL.

Comment: @Geoff: Please have a look in my updated question. I have copied all files and database as well. Everything works fine except the hyperlinks created using CKEditor. These hyperklinks are returning 404 error. Sine there is an unnecessary `/drupal` coming in new URL.

Comment: @CocoSkin: Please have a look in my updated question. Everything works fine except the hyperlinks created using CKEditor. These hyperklinks are returning 404 error. Sine there is an unnecessary `/drupal` coming in new URL. If I manually remove `/drupal` from the URL and type `http://www.example.com/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/eula.pdf`, the file opens successfully.

Comment: And when you now create a new link via CKEditor, does it do it correctly?

Comment: Yes. Newly created links doesn't have unnecessary `/drupal` in it

Comment: @Ravi Joshi Check your file system setting, make sure the path is correct. The setting is on "Configuration > Media > File system".

Comment: @CocoSkin: See the screenshot [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51884474/durpal.png) . Now If i insert hyperlink, it doesn't add `/drupal` but my all old hyperlinks have `/drupal`, which is causing 404 error. I have to manually edit all the pages :(

Comment: @Ravi Joshi so, it was the file system causing this. There are many way to fix the hyperlink in all your body content. One of the way I know is to replace all "/drupal/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/" with "/sites/default/files/docs/pdf/" in database.

Comment: @CocoSkin: I spent my whole night and manually edited all the pages (find and replace). Its working now but sadly, this is a bad experience with drupal.

Comment: @Ravi Joshi As I mentioned. There are many way to fix this issue. You can use the "Search and Replace Scanner"(https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) module, if you are not familiar with database.